# UrlGenerationError in Devise::Sessions#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Hi i have devise running fine in a single controller.

i have now added a second controller that i want to be able to link to in my

navbar but it will not work if devise login links are in the navbar

both work but will not work together

```
UrlGenerationError in Devise::Sessions#new 

<%=link_to "Home ", :controller => :posts, :action => :index %>
```

Comment: Can you post the full error in the question?

Comment: Why don't you use `posts_path` instead?

Comment: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts"} missing required keys: [:id]

Comment: i have just tryed the post_path and got this error 

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts"} missing required keys: [:id]
devise is looking for an id field in post table and i dont have an id field in the posts table.But i want both controllers to use the same id field whats the best way to make the id field avaliable in both controllers

Comment: many thanks it did work i didnt pluralize post